# why my DELETE button dont work in this way

Tags: php

do you have any idea why my DELETE button  do not work. i have just started learning.

```
<?php
    require("mysqli_connect.php");
    $q="SELECT * FROM contact";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$q);
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Text'].'</td>';

        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="'.$row['Id'].'"> 
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="delete"></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
        break;
        }}
        mysqli_close($db);
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='post'){

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            $id=$_POST['itemid'];
            $q2="DELETE FROM contact WHERE Id='$id'";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$q2);



        }}

            ?>
```

I'm just missing something, but I can't figure out what that is

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: `mysqli_close($db);` this is probably in the wrong place

Comment: You need to use javascript and ajax for this functionality. Here form tag and submit button is missing.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: As an aside, I personally think it's a bad idea to delete records.  You should really just add a flag for "deleted" to that row.

Comment: your comment are useful thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is a good practice to try and separate your html and your php as much as possible. Look into AJAX. For simplicity sake run all the php if statements at the top of the page and generate html at the bottom.

```
<?php
    require("mysqli_connect.php");

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $id=$_POST['itemid'];   //This should be escaped for security reasons to avoid sql injection
        $q2="DELETE FROM contact WHERE Id='$id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$q2);
    }

    //PAGE HTML
    $q="SELECT * FROM contact";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$q);
    $i = 1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['Email'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['Text'].'</td>';

            echo '<td><form action="#" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="'.$row['Id'].'">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="delete"></form></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

THe html is generated at the bottom. Each time you submit a foprm the if statement is called at the top of the page. If you didn't submit the form the page loads as normal. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Also note that your user inputted date doesn't get sanitized. Never trust user inputted data, and always assume it is bad. It would be a good idea to prepare the statement or escape that $_POST variable.

Answer (score 0):

1) The "form" tag is missing from your code, before the loop. This way the condition that verify if method is POST returns false.
2) The break in the while loop will stop iterating the results in the first row.